# Event Calendar - how to add multiple <td> table elements

Tags: javascript

I'm doing 'Calendar Event' app. After choosing the day of the week, times and short description I can click on 'Add Event' button and add a row to table (not visible), but I don't know, how to add a cell to it. 
I was trying to add cell, by grabbing '.event' class `var eventContent = document.querySelectorAll('.event');` , and use `appendChild()` method,

```
for(var j = 0; j < eventContent.length; j +=1){
     eventContent[j].appendChild(tdElement1);
     eventContent[j].appendChild(tdElement2);
}
```

but the cells are not inserting as should be, after changing the day of the week.
There is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Daily Programmer Challenge #0004 | Events Calendar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/0004_eventsCalendar.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="toolbarMenu">
                <div class="toolLeft">
                    <div class="leftButtons">
                        <button type="button"><span><</span></button>
                        <button type="button"><span>></span></button>
                    </div>
                        <button type="button">today</button>
                </div>
                <div class="toolCenter">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                </div>           
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="leftSide">
                    <table>                   
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="eventHead">
                                <td class="dayHead" colspan="2"><span class="day">Monday</span><span class="dayDate"></span></td>                                
                            </tr>  
                            <tr class="eventHead">
                                <td class="dayHead" colspan="2"><span class="day">Tuesday</span><span class="dayDate"></span></td>                                
                            </tr>                        

                            <tr class="eventHead">
                                <td class="dayHead" colspan="2"><span class="day">Wednesday</span><span class="dayDate"></span></td>                                
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="eventHead">
                                <td class="dayHead" colspan="2"><span class="day">Thursday</span><span class="dayDate"></span></td>                                
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="eventHead">
                                <td class="dayHead" colspan="2"><span class="day">Friday</span><span class="dayDate"></span></td>                                
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="eventHead">
                                <td class="dayHead" colspan="2"><span class="day">Saturday</span><span class="dayDate"></span></td>                                
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="eventHead">
                                <td class="dayHead" colspan="2"><span class="day">Sunday</span><span class="dayDate"></span></td>                                
                            </tr>

                            <!--

                            <tr class="event">
                                <td class="time"></td>
                                <td class="desc"></td>                             
                            </tr>
                        -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <p><i><strong>Note:</strong> After adding event into table, you can EDIT it!</i></p>
                </div>
                <div id="rigthSide">
                    <h3>Calendar panel</h3>
                    <form id="calendarCMS" name = "calendarCMS" action="#">
                        <fieldset>                            
                            <select name="dayOfWeek" id="dayOfWeek">
                                <option value="monday">Monday</option>
                                <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                                <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                                <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
                                <option value="friday">Friday</option>
                                <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
                                <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>                                
                            </select>                         
                            <div id="fromToTime">
                                <span>from:</span>
                                <select name="fromTime" id="fromTime">                                       
                                    <option value="07.00am">07:00am</option>
                                    <option value="07.15am">07:15am</option>
                                    <option value="07.30am">07:30am</option>
                                    <option value="07.45am">07:45am</option>
                                    <option value="08.00am">08:00am</option>
                                    <option value="08.15am">08:15am</option>
                                    <option value="08.30am">08:30am</option>
                                    <option value="08.45am">08:45am</option>
                                    <option value="09.00am">09:00am</option>
                                    <option value="09.15am">09:15am</option>
                                    <option value="09.30am">09:30am</option>
                                    <option value="09.45am">09:45am</option>
                                    <option value="10.00am">10:00am</option>
                                    <option value="10.15am">10:15am</option>
                                    <option value="10.30am">10:30am</option>
                                    <option value="10.45am">10:45am</option>
                                    <option value="11.00am">11:00am</option>
                                    <option value="11.15am">11:15am</option>
                                    <option value="11.30am">11:30am</option>
                                    <option value="11.45am">11:45am</option>
                                    <option value="12.00am">12:00am</option>
                                    <option value="12.15am">12:15am</option>
                                    <option value="12.30am">12:30am</option>
                                    <option value="12.45am">12:45am</option>
                                    <option value="13.00pm">13:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="13.15pm">13:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="13.30pm">13:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="13.45pm">13:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="14.00pm">14:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="14.15pm">14:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="14.30pm">14:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="14.45pm">14:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="15.00pm">15:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="15.15pm">15:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="15.30pm">15:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="15.45pm">15:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="16.00pm">16:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="16.15pm">16:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="16.30pm">16:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="16.45pm">16:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="17.00pm">17:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="17.15pm">17:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="17.30pm">17:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="17.45pm">17:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="18.00pm">18:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="18.15pm">18:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="18.30pm">18:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="18.45pm">18:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="19.00pm">19:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="19.15pm">19:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="19.30pm">19:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="19.45pm">19:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="20.00pm">20:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="20.15pm">20:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="20.30pm">20:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="20.45pm">20:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="21.00pm">21:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="21.15pm">21:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="21.30pm">21:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="21.45pm">21:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="22.00pm">22:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="22.15pm">22:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="22.30pm">22:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="22.45pm">22:45pm</option>                                   
                                    <option value="23.00pm">23:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="23.15pm">23:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="23.30pm">23:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="23.45pm">23:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="00.00am">00:00am</option>
                                    <option value="00.15am">00:15am</option>
                                    <option value="00.30am">00:30am</option>
                                    <option value="00.45am">00:45am</option>
                                    <option value="01.00am">01:00am</option>
                                    <option value="01.15am">01:15am</option>
                                    <option value="01.30am">01:30am</option>
                                    <option value="01.45am">01:45am</option>
                                    <option value="02.00am">02:00am</option>
                                    <option value="02.15am">02:15am</option>
                                    <option value="02.30am">02:30am</option>
                                    <option value="02.45am">02:45am</option>
                                    <option value="03.00am">03:00am</option>
                                    <option value="03.15am">03:15am</option>
                                    <option value="03.30am">03:30am</option>
                                    <option value="03.45am">03:45am</option>
                                    <option value="04.00am">04:00am</option>
                                    <option value="04.15am">04:15am</option>
                                    <option value="04.30am">04:30am</option>
                                    <option value="04.45am">04:45am</option>
                                    <option value="05.00am">05:00am</option>
                                    <option value="05.15am">05:15am</option>
                                    <option value="05.30am">05:30am</option>
                                    <option value="05.45am">05:45am</option>
                                    <option value="06.00am">06:00am</option>
                                    <option value="06.15am">06:15am</option>
                                    <option value="06.30am">06:30am</option>
                                    <option value="06.45am">06:45am</option>
                                </select> 
                                <span>to:</span>
                                <select name="toTime" id="toTime">                                       
                                    <option value="07.00am">07:00am</option>
                                    <option value="07.15am">07:15am</option>
                                    <option value="07.30am">07:30am</option>
                                    <option value="07.45am">07:45am</option>
                                    <option value="08.00am">08:00am</option>
                                    <option value="08.15am">08:15am</option>
                                    <option value="08.30am">08:30am</option>
                                    <option value="08.45am">08:45am</option>
                                    <option value="09.00am">09:00am</option>
                                    <option value="09.15am">09:15am</option>
                                    <option value="09.30am">09:30am</option>
                                    <option value="09.45am">09:45am</option>
                                    <option value="10.00am">10:00am</option>
                                    <option value="10.15am">10:15am</option>
                                    <option value="10.30am">10:30am</option>
                                    <option value="10.45am">10:45am</option>
                                    <option value="11.00am">11:00am</option>
                                    <option value="11.15am">11:15am</option>
                                    <option value="11.30am">11:30am</option>
                                    <option value="11.45am">11:45am</option>
                                    <option value="12.00am">12:00am</option>
                                    <option value="12.15am">12:15am</option>
                                    <option value="12.30am">12:30am</option>
                                    <option value="12.45am">12:45am</option>
                                    <option value="13.00pm">13:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="13.15pm">13:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="13.30pm">13:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="13.45pm">13:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="14.00pm">14:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="14.15pm">14:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="14.30pm">14:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="14.45pm">14:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="15.00pm">15:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="15.15pm">15:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="15.30pm">15:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="15.45pm">15:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="16.00pm">16:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="16.15pm">16:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="16.30pm">16:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="16.45pm">16:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="17.00pm">17:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="17.15pm">17:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="17.30pm">17:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="17.45pm">17:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="18.00pm">18:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="18.15pm">18:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="18.30pm">18:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="18.45pm">18:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="19.00pm">19:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="19.15pm">19:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="19.30pm">19:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="19.45pm">19:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="20.00pm">20:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="20.15pm">20:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="20.30pm">20:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="20.45pm">20:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="21.00pm">21:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="21.15pm">21:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="21.30pm">21:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="21.45pm">21:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="22.00pm">22:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="22.15pm">22:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="22.30pm">22:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="22.45pm">22:45pm</option>                                   
                                    <option value="23.00pm">23:00pm</option>
                                    <option value="23.15pm">23:15pm</option>
                                    <option value="23.30pm">23:30pm</option>
                                    <option value="23.45pm">23:45pm</option>
                                    <option value="00.00am">00:00am</option>
                                    <option value="00.15am">00:15am</option>
                                    <option value="00.30am">00:30am</option>
                                    <option value="00.45am">00:45am</option>
                                    <option value="01.00am">01:00am</option>
                                    <option value="01.15am">01:15am</option>
                                    <option value="01.30am">01:30am</option>
                                    <option value="01.45am">01:45am</option>
                                    <option value="02.00am">02:00am</option>
                                    <option value="02.15am">02:15am</option>
                                    <option value="02.30am">02:30am</option>
                                    <option value="02.45am">02:45am</option>
                                    <option value="03.00am">03:00am</option>
                                    <option value="03.15am">03:15am</option>
                                    <option value="03.30am">03:30am</option>
                                    <option value="03.45am">03:45am</option>
                                    <option value="04.00am">04:00am</option>
                                    <option value="04.15am">04:15am</option>
                                    <option value="04.30am">04:30am</option>
                                    <option value="04.45am">04:45am</option>
                                    <option value="05.00am">05:00am</option>
                                    <option value="05.15am">05:15am</option>
                                    <option value="05.30am">05:30am</option>
                                    <option value="05.45am">05:45am</option>
                                    <option value="06.00am">06:00am</option>
                                    <option value="06.15am">06:15am</option>
                                    <option value="06.30am">06:30am</option>
                                    <option value="06.45am">06:45am</option>
                                    </select>          
                            </div>
                            <textarea name="eventDesc" id="eventDesc" cols="45" rows="10" placeholder="Please write the description event details"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" value="Add Event">
                        </fieldset>
                        <div id="error"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/0004_eventsCalendar.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
//self-executing function to protect our local variables
(function(){
    // current date
    var curentDate = new Date();
    // set variable to first day of week (Monday)
    var firstDay = (curentDate.getDate() - (curentDate.getDay()-1));
    // array of months
    var allMonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    // loop through to get last day (Friday) of the curent week
    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i +=1){
       var lastDay = firstDay + i;        
    }
    // add the date to DOM element (h2 tag)
    document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = 
    allMonths[curentDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + firstDay + ' - ' + lastDay + ', ' + curentDate.getFullYear();

    // get all DOM nodes with the class name ('.dayDate')
    var dayDate = document.querySelectorAll('.dayDate');
    // loop through those nodes and add to DOM month, current date and year
    for(var i = 0; i < dayDate.length; i+=1){
        dayDate[i].innerHTML = allMonths[curentDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + (firstDay + i) + ', ' +  curentDate.getFullYear();
    }

    // assign form HTML element of Calendar panel to variables. Where '.fromTime' and '.toTome' , are names of <select> tag
    var fromTime = document.calendarCMS.fromTime;
    var toTime = document.calendarCMS.toTime;

    // function for manipulating times (from: and to:), in Calendar panel
    function changeFromTime(e){
        // triger when time in first pop-down menu '.fromTime' is higher than in second pop-down menu '.toTime'
        // where selectedIndex is a number (position) of currently selected element in pop-down menu
        if(fromTime.selectedIndex >= toTime.selectedIndex){
              // loop throogh first pop-down menu 'fromTime', where fromTime.selectedIndex is index curently selected element
              for(var i = 0; i <= fromTime.selectedIndex; i +=1){
                // hide all times in second pop-down menu 'toTime' which are below times in '.fromTime' pop-down menu
                toTime[i].style.display = 'none';
              } 
              // change position '.toTime' pop-down menu index to be equal to first pop-down menu '.froTime'
              return toTime.selectedIndex = i;                            
            }                                                 

       // triger when time in first pop-down menu '.fromTime' is lower than in second pop-down menu '.toTime'
        if(fromTime.selectedIndex <= toTime.selectedIndex){
            // reverse (remove) styling when user change to earlier time, where we removing styling only  to elements which are
            // below curently selected index (i = fromTime.selectedIndex) in '.fromTime' pop-down menu
            for(var i = fromTime.selectedIndex; i < toTime.selectedIndex; i +=1){
                toTime[i].removeAttribute('style');
             }  
             // change position '.toTime' pop-down menu index to be equal to first pop-down menu '.froTime'
             return toTime.selectedIndex = fromTime.selectedIndex; 
        }
    }


    // function use to add/remove calendar events
    function addEvent(e){
        //event will triger only when user press submit 'Add Event' button
        if(e.target.type === 'submit'){
            // prevent submit button from default behavior 
            e.preventDefault();

            // assign a couple of variables
            var textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

            var eventHead = document.querySelectorAll('.eventHead');                        
            var trElement = document.createElement('tr');      
            trElement.className = 'event';


            var eventDesc = document.querySelectorAll('.desc'); 
            var eventTime = document.querySelectorAll('.time');           
            var errMsg = document.querySelector('#error');
            errMsg.style.color = "red";

            // loop through description field in HTML table
            for(var i = 0; i < eventHead.length; i+=1){
                // trigger when option in index in 'dayOfWeek' pop-down menu will match index of description field
                if(document.calendarCMS.dayOfWeek.selectedIndex === i){                  
                    // if textarea in HTML will be empty, then the error msg will pop out, blocking user from adding event
                    if(textArea.value === ''){
                        // error msg show when user doesn't fill all necessary details
                        errMsg.innerHTML = 'Please fill all fields';
                        return;
                    } else{ // if all require filed will be filled
                        /*
                        // after description of event will be added to table, then will be editable
                        eventDesc[i].contentEditable = true;
                        // after times of event will be added to table, then will be editable
                        eventTime[i].contentEditable = true;
                        */                     

                        eventHead[i].parentNode.insertBefore(trElement.cloneNode(true), eventHead[i].nextElementSibling);

                        var eventContent = document.querySelectorAll('.event');
                        var tdElement1 = document.createElement('td');
                        var tdElement2 = document.createElement('td');
                        tdElement1.className = 'time';
                        tdElement2.className = 'desc';


                        for(var j = 0; j < eventContent.length; j +=1){
                           eventContent[j].appendChild(tdElement1);
                           eventContent[j].appendChild(tdElement2);
                        }

                        // reset all field in Calendar panel
                        fromTime.selectedIndex = 0;
                        toTime.selectedIndex = 0;
                        textArea.value = '';
                        errMsg.innerHTML = '';
                    }

                }                
            }
        }
    }

    // function for higlight current day of the week
    function todayDay(e){
        // triger only when user click 'today' button
        if(e.target.textContent === 'today'){
            var focusEvent = document.querySelectorAll('.event');
            // loop through to find the current day of the week and highliht it
            for(var i = 0; i < focusEvent.length; i +=1){
                if(curentDate.getDay() === i){
                    focusEvent[i-1].style.background = 'yellow';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // events listeners
    document.querySelector('#calendarCMS').addEventListener('click', addEvent, false);
    document.querySelector('#fromTime').addEventListener('change', changeFromTime, false);
    document.querySelector('.toolLeft').addEventListener('click', todayDay, false);
})();
```

Comment: Why use want to put something to commented part of HTML? And you are looping through eventContent - so it suggests, that there would be more than one commented row with event class?

Comment: I don't see also what do you want to do with textArea.value - you are checking whether it is not empty in addEvent but there is no usage of this value later on.

Comment: I used `textArea.value` in version 1, where I've just use `innerHTML` method to print values into the cells. It worked, but I could only have one row for every day if calendar:
`}else{
eventDesc[i].innerHTML = textArea.value; 
eventTime[i].innerHTML = fromTime.value + ' - ' + toTime.value;
...
`
but then I thought I could do add more than just one row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not exactly apprehend your attempt with the commented tr class "event". But what you want to achieve (at least inferring from the description) can be done by declaring addEvent as :

```
function addEvent(e){
    //event will triger only when user press submit 'Add Event' button
    if(e.target.type === 'submit'){
        // prevent submit button from default behavior 
        e.preventDefault();

        // assign a couple of variables
        var textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

        var eventHead = document.querySelectorAll('.eventHead');                        
        var trElement = document.createElement('tr');      
        trElement.className = 'event';


        var eventDesc = document.querySelectorAll('.desc'); 
        var eventTime = document.querySelectorAll('.time');           
        var errMsg = document.querySelector('#error');
        errMsg.style.color = "red";

        // loop through description field in HTML table
        for(var i = 0; i < eventHead.length; i+=1){
            // trigger when option in index in 'dayOfWeek' pop-down menu will match index of description field
            if(document.calendarCMS.dayOfWeek.selectedIndex === i){                  
                // if textarea in HTML will be empty, then the error msg will pop out, blocking user from adding event
                if(textArea.value === ''){
                    // error msg show when user doesn't fill all necessary details
                    errMsg.innerHTML = 'Please fill all fields';
                    return;
                } else{ // if all require filed will be filled
                    /*
                    // after description of event will be added to table, then will be editable
                    eventDesc[i].contentEditable = true;
                    // after times of event will be added to table, then will be editable
                    eventTime[i].contentEditable = true;
                    */                     
                                            var newTr = trElement.cloneNode(true);
                    eventHead[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newTr, eventHead[i].nextElementSibling);

                    var eventContent = document.querySelectorAll('.event');
                    var tdElement1 = document.createElement('td');                        
                    var tdElement2 = document.createElement('td');
                    tdElement1.innerText=fromTime.value + " - " + toTime.value;
                    tdElement2.innerText=textArea.value;
                    tdElement1.className = 'time';
                    tdElement2.className = 'desc';


                    for(var j = 0; j < eventContent.length; j +=1){
                       newTr.appendChild(tdElement1);
                       newTr.appendChild(tdElement2);
                    }

                    // reset all field in Calendar panel
                    fromTime.selectedIndex = 0;
                    toTime.selectedIndex = 0;
                    textArea.value = '';
                    errMsg.innerHTML = '';
                }

            }                
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it here : https://jsfiddle.net/dn9v5qf9/

Comment: thx, just what I was looking for!! and I see that I wasn't far from solving it. The mistake I made, was to append to wrong DOM element.
thank you

Comment: as for `<tr>` element with `'.event'` class. That was from version 1, where I didn't not create rows and cells. There were already in HTML code and I just used `InnerHTML` method in JavaScript file to print values into cells. I've commented the last row, so could use it, if I wanted go back to previous version.